# Getting error of parsing the package during updating my new version of apk

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-parser

Android Experts, I have installed signed apk (version 1.6) and on my server I've uploaded apk( version 1.7). Now I am facing problem during Update my apk from server.. I also got Dialog box for Updating but at the end I am getting error as
**"Parser Error, There is a problem parsing the package."** . I found some solution from some links but it doesn't work.

I am waiting for your suggestions, any ideas and your solution.

Thank U.!

Answer (score 1):

You can check following things in your code
1. Already installed Apk name and updated apk name should be same.
2. Both Android Manifest contain same android:minSdkVersion value.

Comment: Hey, THanx Sanjeev.. I hv already done!!! But I think It is another issue, n I could not find out..!! :(

Answer (score 1):

Yeppiee... finally I got my solution.. Actually I put wrong file path during Updating code on "onPostExecute".. So thts why I could not Update my apk and was getting "Parser Error, There is a problem parsing the package"
And One more thing If U r update your apk from server U must have following things:
 - installed Apk name and updated apk name should be same.
 - Both Android Manifest contain same android:minSdkVersion value.(Here My  Android Tablet 4.0.3 and I put minSdkVersion:14)
 - And Last If U r using asp.net U must Add .APK MIME Type to IIS - Microsoft Server Support. In IIS there needs to be a MIME type added to allow IIS to support the .APK file type. 
[Check this link](http://blog.skybyte.com/blog/network-helpdesk/adding-apk-mime-type-to-iis-microsoft-server-support)